# How I let the not authenticate users see the other profile without login in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I let the not authenticate users see the other profile without login in Django, because when not authenticate user try to the users' profile this happen
**Account matching query does not exist** I wanna let them able to see the profile without this problem happen

my view

```
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    view_account = account

    my_account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
    if view_account in my_account.following.all():
        follow = True
    else:
        follow = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
my_account =  Account.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    my_account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
    if view_account in my_account.following.all():
        follow = True
    else:
        follow = False
else:
    follow = False # I'm not sure about how you use follow variable so potentially don't need this
```